# Shopping cart code is not working. getting error for undefined variable

Tags: php, jquery, html, xml

I found this tutorial on making a shopping cart app and It's not working. I get an error about undefined variable bookFound on line 22 where it says `if(!$bookFound)`. I see maybe why it is not defined, I'm thinking maybe because it was defined in the if statement previously  in the code and that is not returning true. Any ways I'm having problems fixing it so if you can make this code work that will be great. The user should be able to click the  button and the div should be updated with calculated results.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $booksInfo = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if(count($booksInfo) > 0)
    {
        $bookFound = false;
        for($i=0; $i< count($booksInfo); $i++)
        {
            if($booksInfo[$i]['bookId'] == $_POST['bookId'])
            {
                $booksInfo[$i]['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                $bookFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$bookFound)  //line 22 where error was found
    {
        $book = array('bookId' => $_POST['bookId'], 'quantity' => $_POST['quantity']);
        array_push($booksInfo, $book);
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $booksInfo;

    $grossTotal = 0;
    for($i=0; $i< count($booksInfo); $i++)
    {
        $aBook = $booksInfo[$i];
        $bookName = getBookName($booksInfo[$i]['bookId']);
        $bookPrice = getPriceForBook($booksInfo[$i]['bookId']);
        $totalPrice = $bookPrice  * $booksInfo[$i]['quantity'];
        $grossTotal+= $totalPrice;
        $str.= '<strong>Name - </strong>'.$bookName;
        $str.= '<br/>';
        $str.= ' <strong>Copies - </strong>'.$booksInfo[$i]['quantity'];
        $str.= '<br/>';
        $str.= '<strong>Price - </strong>$'.$bookPrice. ' * ' .$booksInfo[$i]['quantity'].' = $'.$totalPrice;
        $str.= '<br/><br/>';
    }
    $str.= '<strong>Net Amount - </strong>$'.$grossTotal;
    echo $str;


    function getBookName($id)
    {
        $objXML = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
        foreach($objXML->book as $book)
        {
            if($book['id'] == $id)
            {
                return $book->name;
            }
        }
        return false;       
    }
    function getPriceForBook($id)
    {
        $objXML = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
        foreach($objXML->book as $book)
        {
            if($book['id'] == $id)
            {
                return $book->price;
            }
        }   
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Index:

```
 <body>
    <div class="cart">
        <strong>Your cart</strong>
        <p id = "cart">Cart is empty</p>
    </div>
    <?php 
        $objXML = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
        foreach($objXML->book as $book)
        {
            echo '<div>';
            echo 'Name - ' . $book->name, '<br />';
            echo 'price - $'. $book->price, '<br/>';
     ?>

        Quantity -
        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        -
        <input type="hidden" value = "<?php echo $book['id']; ?>">
        <input type="button" value = "Select this book ">
        <?php 
            echo '</div>';
        }
         ?>
         <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input:button').click(function(){
                    $.post('calculate.php',
                    {
                        bookId : $(this).prev('input:hidden').val(),
                        quantity: $(this).prev().prev('select').val()
                    },
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $('#cart').html(data);
                    }
                    )
                });
            });
         </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: try moving the `$bookFound = false;` statement above the `if(count($booksInfo) > 0)` statement

Comment: It works well now, thanks. I guess the author of the tutorial made an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `$bookFound = false;` statement above the `if(count($booksInfo) > 0)` statement. If the `if(count($booksInfo) > 0){}` block is not executed, `$bookFound` is not initialized for when you get to the `if(!$bookFound){}` block.